# How to auto-repeat function in swift

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I'm creating an app for iOS devices which will monitor price of one stock. I've successfully created a function which collets the data from an API and prints out the current value of stock.

The problem is that when I run the app one (current) price gets printed and it stays like that all the time.

My question is how do I make that function repeat itself every specified amount of time?

This is my viewDidLoad and  is the function I want to repeat every couple of seconds.

Code:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {
let baseURL = "url"
@IBOutlet weak var bitcoinValue: NSTextField!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        getJSON { (usdPrice) -> Void in
            let usdPriceText = usdPrice.description
            self.bitcoinValue.stringValue = usdPriceText 
            print(usdPrice)   
        }  
}
func getJSON(completion: (Double) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: baseURL)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            let swiftyJSON = JSON(data: data!)
            let usdPrice = swiftyJSON["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"].doubleValue
            completion(usdPrice)
        } else {
            print("There was an error!")
        }
    } 
    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: are u want to call a function, repeatedly, after a certain time period ?

Answer (score 10):

You can use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/).

following is a example

```
//in your viewdidload
var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)


// must be internal or public. 
func update() {
// your repeating function
}
```

Comment: Where should I put my function and can I just use name of my function insted of new update function?

Comment: @Anton N You should put you're function the class section and yes you can change the name of the function, but then you would have to change the name of the selector.

Comment: I get this error message:
"2016-01-09 01:48:40.124 Bitfo[2885:397879] -[Bitfo.ViewController getJSON]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000100510
2016-01-09 01:48:40.124 Bitfo[2885:397879] -[Bitfo.ViewController getJSON]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000100510
2016-01-09 01:48:40.125 Bitfo[2885:397879]"

Comment: did u declare any method named getJSON ?

Comment: @Anton N Can you show us the code you have so we can correct it?

Comment: @AntonO. I'll place it in the question

Comment: You can't call `getJSON(completion:)` using NSTimer or any other control that uses the target-action pattern. The method signature does not match. You can call it from within `update()` as Ratul proposed though.

Comment: Aaron Brager is right, you can't pass multiple param in NSTimer, it should be none/one, if there is one, it should be the timer itself, check the [following](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312583/passing-a-block-in-selector)

If you were intended to use thread then more felxibility could be achieved using [following](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2109/_index.html).